# Creating a loop to check if the first or the last letter of a word matches the values of an list

Tags: python, loops

Basically what I have is a list a = ["+", "-"] and a string b = "123-+" .

What I want to do is to make a loop that checks if the first and the last characters of the string 'b' are math operators, if yes then shuffle the world till the first and the last character is a digit.

In other words I want to randmoly shuffle the b = "123-=" into something like b = "1-2+3"

Comment: That's nice, good on you for telling us what you have to do. Good luck

Comment: Do you want to loop over a list of strings such as b or is b the only string you want to loop over?

Comment: What have you tried? We love to help but we want to see a little effort on your part.

Comment: Where is the question?!

Comment: @corn3lius This is what I have done:
while equation_string[len(equation_string) - 1] == "+":

 equation_string  =''.join(random.sample(equation_string,len(equation_string)))

Comment: `shuffle the b = "123-=" into something like b = "1-2+3"` Whaaat ? Why ?

Comment: what happens if you shuffle to `12-+3` is that valid?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what your endgame is, but this might be what you're looking for.
Checking for i in b:

```
def arrange(a,b):

    for i in b:
        if b[0] in a and b[-1] in a:
            listb [ i for i in b]
            listb = random.shuffle(listb)
            listb = ''.join(listb)
            def(a,listb)
```

Comment: If you aren't sure what OP why post an answer, why not post comments?

Comment: I thought I understood what he wanted to do with the code, but not necessarily why he wanted to do it: the task seemed a little strange to me. Based on his question, he wants numbers to lead and and end the string.